# How to scale iframe video to smaller size to fit UIWebView frame in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

My screen has two `UIWebViews` which are set to equal heights.

The top `UIWebView` is `videoWebView` to show a video from Vimeo API using  `loadHTMLString` method. 
The bottom `UIWebView` is the video description which is also an `HTML` String.

The video's `iFrame` size is larger than the videoWebView frame. How do I scale it to fit the videoWebView frame?

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The HTML String for the video is:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/168639256?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="Sleepy Steve" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The `webView` is set to `scalesPageToFit` and 'Aspect Fit' in the storyboard.

Any ideas? I spent quite some time googling but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I had to do to make it work (a little bit of HTML & CSS magic):

1. create a `videoEmbed.html` file in a text editor (Sublime, for example)
2. add the following formatter code in your `videoEmbed.html` file

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>embedded video</title>
   <style>
       .video-responsive{
       overflow:hidden;
       padding-bottom:56.25%;
       position:relative;
       height:0;
       }
       .video-responsive iframe{
       left:0;
       top:0;
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       position:absolute;
       }
   </style>
   ```
3. drag and drop your `videoEmbed.html` file into your Xcode project

Add videoEmbed.html file into your Xcode project - example:

[image: add videoEmbed.html file into your Xcode project - example]

4. In the `ViewController` where you are loading the `HTML String` in the `UIWebView`, add a property:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *videoEmbedHTML;`

5. Finally, add the following code to the `view` where you load the `HTML String` in the `UIWebView`:

   ```
   // create a filePath for the videoEmbed.html file that you added to your Xcode project 
   NSString *videoEmbedFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoEmbed" ofType:@"html"];
   NSError *err;
   self.videoEmbedHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:videoEmbedFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

   NSString *html = [self.videoEmbedHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<embeddedVideo>" withString:self.video.videoLink]; // videoLink is the iframe src html link to load the video from an API endpoint 
   [self.videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
   ```

This is how my `UIWebView` looks now:

[image: new screenshot]

Comment: I tend not to vote if a post explicitly requests upvotes, however this does look very good. Please do omit voting remarks in future though - we prefer voting to happen organically here! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while I was trying to load YouTube videos. The trick is to manipulate the URL itself. Generally the URL you would get looks something like this,
 `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/neV3EPgvZ3g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`.

If you manipulate the width and height it would change the size of iframe in your webView.

### ***In Objective C:***

```
CGFloat width = self.webView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.webView.frame.size.height;
NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7ksb_64XWPA\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", width * 2.6, height * 2.6];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:URL baseURL:nil];
```

### ***In Swift:***

```
var width: CGFloat = webView.frame.size.width;
var height: CGFloat = webView.frame.size.height;
var URL = String(format: "<iframe width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7ksb_64XWPA\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", width * 2.6, height * 2.6)
webView.loadHTMLString(URL, baseURL: nil)
```

**NOTE: The factor of 2.6 is achieved by trial and error. I don't know if there is any logical proof for it.**

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing! 

Answer (score 1):

Please, note style attribute.

```
let toLoadInWebView = "<body style=\"margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden\">"
 + " <iframe  style=\"overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: 
 hidden; height: 0;" + " max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; 
 min-width: 100%; width: 0;    
 scrolling:no;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px\" " + " 
 src=https://google.com\"></iframe>" + "</body>"

 webView.loadHTMLString(toLoadInWebView, baseURL: nil)
```